# Generating Ethereum Address from Mnemonic Seed Phrase in Java

Tags: go-ethereum, ethers.js, private-key, ethereumj, passphrase

I hope you're doing well. I have a question related to Ethereum address generation in Java. I'm currently working on a project and I need to generate an Ethereum address using a mnemonic seed phrase. I was wondering if anyone in our community has experience with this and could guide me on how to achieve it in Java?

I've been researching this topic, but I'm looking for practical examples or sample code snippets that demonstrate the process. If you have any knowledge or resources related to generating Ethereum addresses from a mnemonic seed phrase using Java, I would greatly appreciate your help.
and also if you have method in c++ or Go Please give me suggestion

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Best regards,
Abdul Moiz